# How to interpret fft2() plots for images in MATLAB? What are represented by axes?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fft, fourier-transform

I got the frequency spectrum of a grayscale image using

```
img_shft = fftshift(img_fft);
final_spectrum = im2uint8(mat2gray(log(abs(img_shft)+1)));

imagesc(final_spectrum);
plot(final_spectrum);
```

My output for imagesc is as below. What is represented by the axes? Are x-axis frequency and y-axis amplitude?

[image]

This is my output for plot(). Why are there so many lines of different colors? (I converted my RGB image to grayscale before getting fft2)
What are axes?

[image]

Why can't we get clear and easily interpretable frequency plots as we get when we take fft of signals?
(I'm sorry but I'm new to signal processing)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: How about starting with something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v743U7gvLq0

Comment: I've done some playing around to understand it, [these](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/stuff/blob/main/stuff/dsp/dft2d.ipynb) might help.

Answer (score 2):

```
% Assume your data sequence x[n1,n2] is stored on a 2D MATLAB matrix as:
%
% X = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
%     [ 4, 5, 6 ]    X(i,j) is the i-th row ,j-th column.
%     [ 7, 8, 9 ]
%     [10, 11,12]
% 
% MATLAB treats the i-rows as the first dimension, n1; whereas the 
% j-columns as the second dimension, n2. And Top-Left is the first
% element x[0,0] (origin of n1-n2 axes).
%
% The DTF of x[n1,n2] is defined to be f[k1,k2] = DFT{x[n1,n2]}
% and it's given by F = fft2(X), matrix of the same size:
%
% F = [ F11, F12, F13 ]
%     [ F21, F22, F23 ]    F(i,j) is the i-th row ,j-th column.
%     [ F31, F32, F33 ]    i-rows is the 1st dim k1
%     [ F42, F42, F43 ]    j-cols is the 2nd dim k2
%
%
% To display the 2D spectrum magnitude |F| of X, you can use imshow() 
% function, which maps matrix elements to display pixels in an order 
% preserving manner; i.e., top left matrix element |F11| is displayed
% on the top-left pixel of the image window...
%
% The dimensions k1,k2 of F are the w1 and w2 frequency axes of 
% the DTFT respectively. The value of the element at (k1,k2) is the
% value of the 2D DFT/FFT F(k1,k2).
```